# Swift - Alternative way to declare variable outside of viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to initialise a variable to be used in the whole of the program but how would you do this outside of the viewDidLoad() function.

Currently the variable "wordToUse" is declared in the viewDidLoad() function but then I can't access it elsewhere in the program to be compared with when a button is pressed so how can it be declared so that it can initialised once the program has started up and then used throughout the program?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lettersUsed: UILabel!

var lives = 5

var wordList = ["Watch", "Phone", "Apple", "Technology", "Swift", "Computing", "Software", "Hardware", "Computers", "Processor", "Swift", "Java", "Python", "Programming", "Development", "Microsoft", "DropBox", "Facebook"]


var wordToUse: String {
    println(wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))])
    return wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))]
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var wordToUseList = Array(wordToUse)


    for var index = 0; index != wordToUseList.count; ++index {
        wordToUseList[index] = "*"
    }

    wordLabel.text = String(wordToUseList)
    println(wordToUseList)
    livesText.text = String(lives)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

Comment: BTW, inside `wordToUse`, what you are printing is not guaranteed to be returned as it's random. so you need to take the `wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))]` into a variable and then print that variable and return the same. (just to ensure that your logs are not lying to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have a global variable. So you simply declare it outside the class declaration:

```
var wordList = ["Watch", "Phone", "Apple", "Technology", "Swift", "Computing", "Software", "Hardware", "Computers", "Processor", "Swift", "Java", "Python", "Programming", "Development", "Microsoft", "DropBox", "Facebook"]


var wordToUse: String {
    println(wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))])
    return wordList[Int(arc4random_uniform(18))]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     ...
}
```

Comment: So placing it `viewController.swift` is only for semantic purposes? ie it could have been defined in any other swift file?

Comment: @Honey Yes, you can place it in any other swift file. However it does not change it's semantics.